Got failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) from /10.0.2.16 (port 35802) after 10000ms error when connect android to local API using retrofit
My android project have a server. This is my configure

In my MainViewModel file

class MainViewModel :ViewModel(){
    private val _filmRespone: MutableState<filmState> = mutableStateOf(filmState())
    val filmRespone = _filmRespone
    init {
        fetchFilms()
    }

    fun updateFilmState(loading:Boolean = false, error:Boolean = false, respone: List<FILM>  = listOf(), e:String = ""){
        _filmRespone.value = _filmRespone.value.copy(
            loading = loading,
            error = error,
            respone = respone,
            e = e,
        )
    }
    fun fetchFilms(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val respone = SimpleAPI("http://10.0.2.2:8080/").retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java).getFilmsLocalAPI()
                updateFilmState(false, false, respone.body()?.results?: listOf(), respone.message())
            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.d("ERROR", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
    data class filmState(
        val loading:Boolean = false,
        val error:Boolean = false,
        val respone:List<FILM> = listOf(),
        val e:String = "",
    )
}

-In my SimpleApi file
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
    .newBuilder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyMTIzIiwiaWF0IjoxNzEzOTYwNDkyLCJleHAiOjE3MTQ4NDk1MjV9.ULWIVj4PwS_a5oxPGWNYHvrWHfQJkLv-3_wNabHCGeQ")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
    .build()
open class SimpleAPI(base_url:String) {
    val retrofit = Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(base_url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}


And in my APIService file

interface ApiService {
    @GET("api/v1/films")
    suspend fun getFilmsLocalAPI():Response<filmRespone>
}

I don't know where my program is wrong. I added internet permission, added network_security_config.xml file. Forwarded port. But i just can get and update data from my postman
